# How to amplify & clean up a weak reel-to-reel recording for converting to digital?

Tags: audio-recording, signal-processing

I am in the process of converting old reel-to-reel and cassette tape recordings to digital.  One reel-to-recording from the early 70’s of my first band is real weak.  When I amplify the sound the tape rumble is also amplified.  I’ve tried EQing out the lows & highs and compressing.  But, the rumble is still overwhelming and must be sharing the mid range of the vocals.  A faint guitar is present and maybe a bass but I can’t hear it.  I do not remember what recorder was used for the original mono recording but I am playing it back on Akai GX-747 without Dolby NR and sending it to Sonar 7 thru a Sonar V-Studio 100.  I have not tried cleaning it up in Sonar 7 yet because I am still trying to improve the input signal first.  What would you do to rescue this important memory?

Comment: Since you mention it was recorded on a different recorder, could this be a head alignment issue?

Comment: I think Friend has the right diagnosis - the symptoms you describe could easily fit with a head alignment issue.

Comment: @FriendOfGeorge How would one go about confirming that it is in fact a head alignment issue?

Comment: Ask a tape tech to look at the alignment of your reel-to-real unit.

Comment: i think that if head alignment was off he would hear something louder and something softer, i don't know if the louder part could be the rumble. I'll throw another idea , can you disable the NR? i don't really know how NR works in consumer grade tapedecks but NR is for a signal passing through, If the NR is on and the tape is recorded with no NR it's possible that it decodes a not encoded signal... it's an extreme thought anyways..

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that the number of tracks on the recording doesn't match the number of tracks on your Akai-GX747.   Remember that both 2-track 2-channel stereo and 4-track 20-channel stereo recorders were common in the 1970's.